# How to change touch gestures bindings in utouch on 11.10 and above to match the ones in 10.10?

Tags: 11.10, 13.10, 10.10, multi-touch

When upgrading from 10.10 I noticed that touch gesture bindings have changed, from middle click via 3-finger touch, I need 5 fingers and 3 fingers is snap-move.
I tried to search online for a way to change the bindings and found nothing of use.

Is it possible to change the gesture-action binding? If so, how?

If it can only be done by code changes, I would be happy for a project or file reference to start looking at.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer? 11.10 isn't supported any more.

Comment: It is still valid for any of the versions that followed it.

Comment: Can you please reword it and update it for one of the supported versions? Thanks. Ping me when you're done.